# How do some web pages change data without any trace of network activity?

Tags: html, web

I have seen some websites especially the ones that involve currency/cryptocurrency/stocks exchange rates, how are they able to display the latest currency exchange in the browser while also not having any trace of network activity in the browser tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely they are using either [Server-sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) or [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

For example, if you go to https://bitcointicker.co/, there are constant price updates.  If you look in Chrome devtools, there are no new network requests happening.  However, if you are looking at the Network tab, and click on "WS" (for websocket), there will be a single request.  If you click on it, and then click on messages, you will see a stream of data.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into Websockets, that is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

All website now use Ajax to update content , they just update a small part of web site.

Comment: A true AJAX call would leave a network event in the browser console. Take a look at @Dave’s answer, which almost certainly describes what the OP is seeing.

Comment: Yes , that's true... i just misunderstood the question.